# Номер мат. платы на C#

Tags: c#

Весь день пробую написать код, ни как не получается! Помогите примером РАБОЧИМ, который бы показал номер мат. платы.

Расскажу задумку, хочу каждый компьютер идентифицировать по какому-ту параметру, если есть другие идеи то пишите.

Answer (score 2):

Стандартный способ - это запрос WMI. Если WMI содержит номер, он будет извлечен.

```
var results = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT SerialNumber FROM Win32_BaseBoard");

foreach (var board in results.Get())
{
    foreach (var property in board.Properties)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", property.Name, property.Value);
}
```

Но, к сожалению, далеко не на всех платах он есть. Поэтому лучше взять другой параметр, вроде MAC-адреса или номера процессора.

```
foreach (var ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    Console.WriteLine(ni.GetPhysicalAddress());
}
```

Comment: ругается на ManagementObjectSearcher, говорит не может найти такого, а я using System.Management; подключил, и так весь день...

Comment: Недостаточно указать `using`, необходимо еще добавить ссылку на сборку `System.Management`.

Comment: так я и добавил:

using System;
using System.Management;

все равно не хочет находить...

Comment: копирую пример полностью с msdn, компилятор не хочет находить ManagementObjectSearcher, правда работаю не в VS, а в SharpDeveloper, есть разница?

Comment: @johniek_comp Так вы не туда добавили-то! Надо добавить в References библиотеку System.Management.dll, она по умолчанию не подключается-то.

Comment: разобрался, подключил, но вылазит исключение, как его обработать через try/catch?